# Y-axis scale independent, with double shadow

Tags: vega-lite

Any questions about the use of reslove?,reslove independent & shared,facet reslove independent & shared,but looks not work.now Y-axis scale independent, with double shadowm,actually just need share the same Y-axis, code reproduce via this link https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "facet": { "row": { "field": "Name"} },
  "resolve": {
    "axis": { "x": "independent", "y": "independent" }
  },
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
        "x": { "field": "Cylinders", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": { "zero": true},
            "axis": { "orient": "left"}
        }
    },
    "layer":[
       { 
        "mark": "bar",
        "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "Acceleration", "type": "quantitative","aggregate":"count"}}
       },
       { 
        "mark": "bar",
        "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "Acceleration", "type": "quantitative","aggregate":"sum"}}
       }
    ],
    "resolve": {
        "scale": { "y": "independent" }
    }
  }}
```

[image]

Comment: Please create a reproducible example and include a link to the Vega online editor so that others can try out your code and try to help you https://vega.github.io/editor/#/

Comment: Thanks for reminding, the online Editor has been updated

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. Could you clarify what you are expecting the desired outcome to look like? The reason you are getting the "shadow" is because you are putting two axis on top of each other that have different ranges (e.g. count and acceleration)